# Rails 5 custom database types? For GIS + MariaDB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gis, mariadb

For the 10th time I need to do some GIS stuff in a project, in the pass all I needed was lat/long datatypes and used Solr or something else to process them, now I don't want to that and I want to be capable of using MariaDB/Mysql GIS features.

I don't a problem on creating my queries by hand, that's cool when I need to GET something, but when I want to create or update Rails is making my life difficult.

So I'm asking if someone knows how to add code in the RAILS to DB and DB to RAILS part to correctly parse the data.

Eg:

I want to have a POLYGON in my table:

```
create_table :venues, options: 'ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' do |t|
    t.column :name, :string
    t.column :geofence, :geometry
    t.timestamps
end
```

No problem with that, let's ditch Rails for a moment and let's do a normal insert, peace of cake:

```
INSERT INTO venues (name, geofence) VALUES ('A Name', PolygonFromText('POLYGON((25.774 -80.190,18.466 -66.118,32.321 -64.757,32.321 -64.757,25.774 -80.190))'));
```

Now if you want to this in Rails you can't, because it treats the `:geometry` like a string, so can't do any of these:

```
v = Venue.new(name: 'hello')
v.geofence = "PolygonFromText('POLYGON((25.774 -80.190,18.466 -66.118,32.321 -64.757,32.321 -64.757,25.774 -80.190))')"
v.save
```

Because it will add quotes and stuff to the inserts and updates. Like this:

`INSERT INTO venues (name, geofence, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('A name', 'PolygonFromText(\"POLYGON((25.774 -80.190,18.466 -66.118,32.321 -64.757,32.321 -64.757,25.774 -80.190))\")', '2016-09-21 16:56:23', '2016-09-21 16:56:23')`

So, I just want to avoid Rails add those for me, and have the ability to assign EXACTLY what I need to do inserts.

Thanks guys, hope you can help me.